# Connect to Azure KeyVault via SQL Connect failed with Error code 3113

Tags: sql-server

I have a task to enable SQL Server database encryption with an Azure Key Vault. I follow the steps described in [Set up SQL Server TDE Extensible Key Management by using Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/setup-steps-for-extensible-key-management-using-the-azure-key-vault?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=portal).
More details as following

1. In my Azure portal, I created a Key Vault, named DB-Encryption-POC and added a Key management Access policy with all permissions.
2. In the Key vault I created a RSA 2048 Key named DBEncryptionKey1
3. In Active Directory I registered an App named test-keyvault
4. In Key Vault DB-Encryption-POC, I added a Key management Access policy with all permissions and set the service principal as test-keyvault. I hope this will hook my app test-keyvault with the access permissions
5. In the App test-keyvault, I created a secret

[image]

Comment: You'd be better off posting the error text than an image which is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

You said in 2. you created an rsa 2048 key named DBEncryptionKey1, but the error shows you are trying to find a key named EncryptionDBKey1, looks like at the very least the name is mismatched?